# Как скрыть блок при достижении футера

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, fixed

Есть блок, который начинает ехать за скролом, но нужно что бы он при достижении футера, или 250 px от низа страница скрывался
Пробовал такой код в ready закинуть, но все равно он прячется раньше чем нужно (на станице есть реклама которая грузится после загрузки страницы)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var sTop = jQuery('.list-group').offset().top;
var sLeft = jQuery('.list-group').offset().left;
var sHeight = jQuery('.list-group').height();
var fTop = jQuery('.footer').offset().top;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if (top >= 750 && (top + sHeight) <= fTop) {
        jQuery('.list-group').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px', 'left': sLeft + 'px' });
    } else {
        jQuery('.list-group').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: может если позиции могут поменяться, то стоит пересчитывать их при скролле?